# With AWS, why I can't access my file, however it exists?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Hello Awesome People!**

The issue is with django 1.11, python 3.5

I am struggling with it since 6 hours.

When I visit the link into a browser, it shows the file correctly.

```
http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/media/public/path/to/file.pdf
```

But when I do this:

```
with open(absolute_path, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(object_content)
```

I get the following error:

> Exception Type:   FileNotFoundError
>   Exception Value:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/media/public/path/to/file.pdf`'

Why I can't access the file?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Django, but can you use `open` on a remote URL? Isn't this only for opening local files? What about using _requests_? `request = requests.get(absolute_path)`

Comment: This is not specific to Django and @MattClark is right. You cannot open URLs using `open`. S3 files are not disk files. You should use something like `requests` or even better an AWS API library such as `boto`

Comment: Ok got it @MattClark! I am using `boto` @Selcuk. What I want is to write the bytes file coming from AWS bucket into another existing file, so I can add it to my zip package

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the body of the S3 object into a variable, then you can use [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as follows

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('my-bucket', 'cat.jpg')
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

If you want to download files from S3 to a local file, then:

```
import boto3
import botocore
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket('my-bucket').download_file('cat.jpg', '/tmp/cat.jpg')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

If you want to upload files to S3:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('my-bucket').put_object(Key='test.jpg', Body=data)
```

Comment: No! I want to download file from S3...What I want is to write the bytes file coming from AWS bucket into another existing file, so I can add it to my zip package

Comment: interesting! `body = obj.get()['Body'].read()` from this line, the file is bytes object, I want to convert it to a file, so I can add it into a zip package. This is very useful, I want to up-vote it, not enough reputation